# Create map of segregated values from two lists in stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to create map of two lists. First List is used for keys and second to segregate and assign values, wherein situation, where there are no values matching bin assigned, will be empty List. Values should be assigned like to key 5 values <50, 60), so having

> sampleBins = Arrays.asList(0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60);
>
> samples = Arrays.asList(5, 6, 55, 52);

I'd like to have Map that will have keys: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6.
Empty Lists for key 1, 2, 3, 4, 6.
List out of 5, 6 assigned to key 0 and 55, 52 assigned to 5.

Right now I have it like this, it's working but I'm searching for something better, for example, solution that will not require sampleBins and will fit in one pipeline

```
private Map<Integer, List<Integer>> segregateSamples(List<Double> sampleBins, List<Double> samples) {

    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> segregatedSamples = sampleBins.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(bin -> bin.intValue() / 10, bin -> new ArrayList<>()));

    samples.stream()
        .map(Double::intValue)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(this::binNumber))
        .forEach(segregatedSamples::put);

    return segregatedSamples;
}

private Integer binNumber(int value) {
    return Math.floorDiv(value, 10);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the method to classify your samples is fixed. The only difference the bins are making is to specify what you are interested in. Therefore, in the first place, there is no too much need to pay attention to your bins.

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> segregateSamples(List<Integer> sampleBins, List<Integer> samples) {

    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> groupedSamples = samples.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> 10 * x / 10));

    return sampleBins.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), b -> 
            groupedSamples.getOrDefault(b, Collections.emptyList())));
}
```

This function first groups your samples, then based on your interested bins, either extract list out of the map, or create a empty list if it's absent.

Comment: damn. there should be a thing that if a person has high enough reputation, he should see the names of the downvoters.

Comment: I agree, someone seems to be downvoting both of ours.

Comment: @JacobG. i'd imagine some junior asked elementary question in a bad way and got bashed by people. now he's revenging by downvoting every answers and questions he can catch.

Comment: To be honest I also don't understand downvoting you guys, at least without providing reason

Answer (score 1):

Here's my first solution, which essentially combines yours into a single statement.  Note that this is expensive to perform with large lists, so I will look for something more efficient in the meantime:

```
sampleBins.stream()
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(bin -> bin / 10, bin ->
              samples.stream()
                     .filter(i -> i - i % 10 == bin)
                     .collect(Collectors.toList())
          ));
```

This outputs the following:

> {0=[5, 6], 1=[], 2=[], 3=[], 4=[], 5=[55, 52], 6=[]}

Here is another solution which is pretty simple:

```
samples.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i - i % 10));
```

However, it will output the following instead of setting the other bins to empty `List`s, which may or may not be a problem in your case since you can simply check if the bin exists as a key in the `Map`:

> {0=[5, 6], 50=[55, 52]}

I'll edit my post if I find anything else interesting, so keep an eye out!

Comment: i - i % 10 - equels  0 % 10

Comment: @SeniorPomidor It doesn't due to operator precedence.

Comment: It is important for further calculations to keep solution with empty Lists if there is no value matching

Comment: I see.  My first solution would work perfectly for you then.  I'll try for something better in the meantime.  How big is your dataset, by the way?

Comment: I assume 9k tops per request, but normally less than 1k

Answer (score 1):

How about concat lists and then create single parallel stream?

```
private Map<Integer, Collection<Integer>> segregateSamples(List<Double> sampleBins, List<Double> samples) {
    Stream<Double> d = Stream.concat(sampleBins.stream(), samples.stream()).parallel();
    return d.collect(Collectors.groupingByConcurrent(p -> (p.intValue() / 10),
                    Collectors.mapping(Double::intValue, Collectors.toCollection(ArrayDeque::new))));
}
```

The only disadvantage is that every collection contains its key.